# What is the formal definition of the singular support of a distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

The definition I have is that：For a distribution $u \in \mathcal{D}'(U)$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, a point $x$ is in the singular support of $u$ if $u$ is not smooth on an open set containing $x$.

This definition does not make sense to me. How should one interpret the smoothness of $u$ on an open open subset of $U$? The only thing that I can think of is that $u$ is smooth if $u$ can be given by integration against a smooth function, but I am not sure whether this is the right definition or not.

For instance take $f \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb R^n)$, $F \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R^n)$, how is $fF$ a compactly supported smooth function which is supposed to be only a distribution by definition?

Comment: A point is in the singular support of a distribution $T$ if there exists no neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ with: there is a $f\in C^\infty(U)$ so that for all smooth $g$ vanishing outside of $U$ you have $T(g) = \int f g$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Definition:** Let $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We say that $u$ is smooth near of $x_0$ if there exists a open neighbourhood $\omega$ of $x_0$ sucht that $u|_{\omega} \in C^\infty(\Omega)$.

**Definition:** Let $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$, we say that $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ if there exists $f \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $T_f=u$, where $T$ is the canonic injection of $C^\infty$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$.

**Definition:** The singular support of a distribution $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ is defined by $\operatorname{sing supp} u=\Omega \setminus\{x \in \Omega: u \hbox{ is smooth near of } x \}$.

It's easy to see that $\operatorname{sing supp} u$ is the complementary set of biggest subset of $\Omega$ in which $u \in C^\infty$.

Comment: Is it true that multiplication of a distribution $u$ by a smooth compactly support function $f$ produces something that is smooth?

Comment: No, consider $F=\delta_0$ and $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1$ and $\varphi=1$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, then $\varphi F=\delta_0$.

Comment: Just to remark: $u\lvert_\omega \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ means that there is an $f$ so that $u(g) = T_f(g)$ for all $g$ _supported in $\omega$_.

Comment: @s.harp That's right! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: and whith similar logic ¿can i say $u$ a distribution is $C^j$ class if exist $f\in C^j(\Omega)$ such that $Tf=u$ ?