# Combining Fractions with Delta Function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, fractions, signal-processing

The Fourier Transform of $u(t)$ is $\frac{1}{jω} + \piδ(ω)$.

However I'm troubled with the following fact:

$\frac{1}{jω} + πδ(ω) = \frac{1+jωπδ(ω)}{jω} = \frac{1+j0πδ(ω)}{jω} = \frac{1}{jω}$

So is the Fourier Transform of $u(t)$ just $\frac{1}{jω}$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The $\delta$ would correspond to a constant (added) term in $u(t)$. So no, it makes a difference, and you should not make the $\delta$ disappear.

Comment: @DominikS Thank you for your input; however, I still can't see what I've done wrong in my calculations

Comment: I think you should not treat $\delta$ as a function that is zero everywhere and infinite at $\omega=0$. It is a distribution, and so is $\omega\delta(\omega)$ and $\omega\delta(\omega)/\omega$. Two distributions $\phi_1, \phi_2$ are the same if they are the same on all test functions (or Schwarz functions): $\int \phi_1 f d\omega = \int \phi_2 f d\omega$ should hold for all $f\in \mathcal S$.

Comment: More specifically, you can't simply say that $\omega \delta(\omega)  = 0$ by pointwise "evaluation" of this distribution for every $\omega$, but you should ask: "What is the action of $\omega\delta(\omega)$ on $f$, i.e. what is $\int \omega\delta(\omega) f(\omega) d\omega$. Indeed, one finds that this is $(\omega f(\omega))|_{\omega=0}=0$. Note how this approach is different.

Comment: Analogously, you can't say $\omega \delta / \omega = 0\delta /\omega = 0 $, but you have to treat $\omega \delta /\omega$ as a distribution as a whole.

Comment: $\omega \delta(\omega)$ is in fact equal to $0$ as a distribution, but $\omega\delta(\omega)/\omega$ isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Let us just look at what is going on with the $\delta(\omega)$ term:
$$
\pi\delta(\omega)
\stackrel{1}{=} \pi\delta(\omega)\cdot 1
\stackrel{2}{=} \pi\delta(\omega)\cdot(\omega\cdot\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{\omega})
\stackrel{3}{=} (\pi\delta(\omega)\cdot\omega)\cdot\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{\omega}
\stackrel{4}{=} 0\cdot\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{\omega}
\stackrel{5}{=} 0.
$$
(Here, "pv" stands for [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) and is just a notation to specify how integration against $\frac{1}{\omega},$ which has divergent integrals at origin, should be done.)

Step 1: Multiplication with $1$ is well-defined no matter if we consider $1$ to be just a number, a smooth function, or a distribution. Generally multiplication of distributions is not defined, but when the two distributions have disjoint [singular support](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3647348/168433), as is the case here, the product can be defined.

Step 2: It is true that $1=\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{\omega}\cdot\omega$ in the distribution sense, but now we are getting close to a problem: if we remove the parentheses we have a product involving two distributions that have non-disjoint singular support. Both $\delta(\omega)$ and $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{\omega}$ have singular support $\{0\}.$

Step 3: Here is where the problem occurs. Although both sides might be defined, **multiplication of distributions obviously is not associative**. This is most probably related to what I wrote before about $\delta(\omega)$ and $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{\omega}$ having non-disjoint singular support.

Step 4: This step is similar to step 2 and I cannot see any real problem here.

Step 5: Also this step is fine, just as step 1.